# What is the purpose this bracket: [0] in Python

Tags: python, list

I found some code that helped me to accomplish incrementing (numerically) files in a particular folder. However, I don't understand why [0] was used in a certain section in the code. Here is a portion of the code, thanks:

```
...
...
numList = [0]
for dlogs in sampleList:
    i = os.path.splitext(dlgs)[0] #Why here?
    try:
        num = re.findall('[0-9]+$', i)[0]    # and here?
        numList.append(int (num))

        ...
        ...
        ...
```

I understand crystal clear now. I could not see that before ... thanks. For those who voted my question down, everyone has to start somewhere. If my question seemed too elementary, why not conserve your energy and just skip my question.

Comment: as an experiment, try this out on the python interpreter and you'll understand the purpose of the brackets: `myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and `print myList[0], myList[2], myList[1]`

Comment: Maybe I got what you don't understand. os.path.splitext() returns a tuple, while re.findall() returns a list. The [0] there is to omit another line of code, to create a variable that points to the return values of the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the lines you ask about, those functions return lists, and the first item (index 0) of each list is being assigned to a variable. For example:

```
>>> os.path.splitext("foo.txt")
('foo', '.txt')
>>> ('foo', '.txt')[0]
'foo'
```

Answer (score -1):

This is for initialising the array or set of variables to 0

Comment: Absolutely not. `[0]` is used to access the first element the first element of the iterables here.

Comment: @rxdazn The first occurrence *is* a list. (Not an array and not a set.)

Comment: @glglgl yes. But I was talking about the lines where he wrote comments. Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the first one.